# Старое отображение кода - ASP, VS2010

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, asp.net-webforms, visual-studio

**Добрый день!**
Столкнулся вчера с такой  ситуацией:

Открываю вчера старый проект в VS2011, добавляю веб-форму, а мне студия не генерирует cs-ый файл, и весь код С#-ый содержится на самой aspx-странице. Пробовал добавлять существующие веб-страницы, добавляется опять же только aspx-файл. Пробовал вручную прописывать Codebehind, не помогло - этот нельзя там создать события.

**Как это можно исправить?
Заранее спасибо**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переустановка студии помогла